# how does || work ,in if(++abc||++xyz) which one is gonna get incremented abc or xyz

Tags: c

how does `||` work in c eg: `++abc||++xyz` output?

```
int abc = 50, xyz = 100;

if (++abc || ++xyz)
     printf("%d %d",abc, xyz);
else
     printf("Chitkara University");
```

Comment: `||` basically means *OR* and the way you are using it is wrong

Comment: `abc` is incremented and then maybe `xyz`

Comment: does ++abc OR ++xyz sound like a condition??

Comment: Have you tried to run this? What did it print? What did you expect to get printed?

Answer (score 4):

This is essentially equivalent to:

```
int abc = 50, xyz = 100;
abc = abc + 1;
if (abc != 0) {
    printf("%d %d", abc, xyz);
} else {
    xyz = xyz + 1;
    if (xyz != 0) {
        printf("%d %d",abc, xyz);
    }
    else {
        printf("Chitkara University");
    }
}
```

`++var` is a pre-increment. This means the variable is incremented, then its value is used in the `if` condition expression. But because `||` is a short-circuiting logical operator, it only executes the second expression if the first expression is false. So `xyz` only gets incremented and tested if incrementing `abc` results in `0`.